# Checkout page issue Internet Explorer in Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

I am using Internet explorer browser, Checkout page is simply loading with loader image.

It is working fine in all other browsers, I am getting below error in console.

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'find'.
```

What is the fix for this? Please anyone suggest on this.

Comment: Do you have the file and line number?

Comment: I have resolved this issue long back, Thanks!!

Comment: great! please write the answer and close the question :)

Comment: Hi jafar pinjar, plz suggest how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788536/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-find-in-ie/37788681

I hope this may help you.

Comment: Plz give me screenshot